# Why do I get "Header file missing" (make error)?

Tags: c, ruby, geocoding, fpic

I'm trying to install a geocoder for a website I'm building. I'm using [Geocoder](https://github.com/geocommons/geocoder) because the query limit for the Google Maps API falls short of my needs.  I installed all the gems required and have SQLite3.  When I'm actually trying to install the geocoder gem (Geocoder::US) I get an error while running the make file.

I'm getting an error I cannot figure out.  It mentions the error (in the title) then talks of an non-existent file (*sqlite3ext.h*). Here is the error:

[image]

I know this is vague but I've been working for 10+ hours trying to *install* this and have found little help online. Any advice on which direction to go would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of linking to an image, *include* a summarized version of the text. That helps us search for other possible fixes, and lets the search engines index this page better, helping others find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the project's [Readme](https://github.com/geocommons/geocoder#prerequisites):

> To build Geocoder::US, you will need gcc/g++, make, bash or equivalent,
>   the standard *NIX ‘unzip’ utility, and the SQLite 3 executable and
>   development files installed on your system.

It seems that you lack the SQLite3 development headers.

This is relevant:

> NOTE: If you do not have /usr/include/sqlite3ext.h installed, then
>   your sqlite3 binaries are probably not configured to support dynamic
>   extension loading. If not, you must compile and install SQLite from
>   source, or rebuild your system packages. This is not believed to be a
>   problem on Debian/Ubuntu, but is known to be a problem with Red
>   Hat/CentOS.

Also they do not mention Windows. You should:

1. Ask them if someone uses it on Windows and if there are instructions for that.
2. Evaluate the thing on Linux, Debian/Ubuntu especially.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it seems like its more difficult on windows to implement by Ive been _assured_ it will work. I downloaded the sqlite-amalgamation folder which has shell.c, sqlite3.c, sqlite3.h, sqlite3.h.ghc, **sqlite3ext.h**, and sqlite3ext.h.ghc. Would you have any idea how to get these files in the proper directories?  Thanks in advance

Comment: for the record I'm using windows server 2012 (a windows 8 format)

Comment: FOUND THE SOLUTION: you need to change the build code for windows.  The instructions are only for linux.

Answer (score 0):

`-fPiC` is not your problem. As the log states, the compiled code is already position independent. The problem is, that the `sqllite3ext.h` is not in the compiler include path.

Comment: Changed that, thanks for your input, title was definitely misleading